AWS EventBridge second call do not exectute lambda
I have 2 AWS lambda functions.
1 lambda:
const sendMessage = async (data) => {
  const ebClient = new EventBridgeClient({});
  const params = {
    Entries: [ 
      {
        Detail: JSON.stringify(data),
        DetailType: 'Message',
        EventBusName: 'default',
        Source: 'sendEvent',
        Time: new Date()
      }
    ]
  }
  const command = new PutEventsCommand(params);
  await ebClient.send(command);
}

export const handler = async (event) => {
  for await (const dta of event.params.data) {
    sendMessage(dta);
  }
}

and 2 lambda have only console.log now.
all works fine, but if i remove await from this line: await ebClient.send(command);, second lambda doesn't call second time by eventbridge.
can someone help me?

It's because when you remove the await keyword, the function does not wait for ebClient.send(command); to complete. Instead, it continues iterating the loop for all messages and then exits the Lambda function. This can lead to unexpected behavior.
Since you tested with only two messages, I suspect the request for the 2nd message was canceled because the Lambda function completed its operation before the second message reached your second Lambda function.
Ensure to use await keyword to wait for the asynchronous operation to complete, so that you will get expected results.
